# GCC C++11 Fails to See #if windows And #if linux (Re-ask)

Tags: c++, c, linux, c++11, gcc

When using the #if windows/#if linux compilers features in Debian GCC version 4.7.2, I have been unable to get them work when using std11.

Independently, I can get the compiler to accept the if-defines without complaint. I can also get the compiler to use the same code with c++ 11, without any if-defines (and thus not conditionally). But when I run the conditional defines through the same compiler, with the tag for c++ 11, the code is rejected.

Below I have included a simple example, with two alternate mains, and the error I get. The only difference between the two mains are the commented out lines.

Runs:

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -o test
```

The above uses the c++ 11 standard. When running **commented main** it works perfectly. But when running **uncommented main**, it fails entirely, giving the error at the far end of this post.

```
g++ main.cpp -o test
```

The above does not use the c++ 11 standard. When running either **commented main** or **uncommented main** it works perfectly.

Below are the code examples.

**Commented main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>

//#if windows
//#include "WindowsSolution.hpp"
//#endif

//#if linux
#include "LinuxSolution.hpp"
//#endif

int main()
{
    std::cout << myGlobalSolution.out() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**LinuxSolution.hpp**:

```
class LinSolution{
public:
    LinSolution(){

    }
    std::string out(){
        std::string ret("Linux solution");
        return ret;
    }
};
LinSolution myGlobalSolution;
```

**WindowsSolution.hpp**:

```
class WinSolution{
private:
    WinSolution(){

    }
    std::string out(){
        std::string ret("Windows solution");
        return ret;
    }
};
WinSolution myGlobalSolution;
```

**Uncommented main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>

#if windows
#include "WindowsSolution.hpp"
#endif

#if linux
#include "LinuxSolution.hpp"
#endif

int main()
{
    std::cout << myGlobalSolution.out() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the error I get when compiling with the **uncommented main.cpp**, using the c++ 11 flag.

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:13:15: error: ‘myGlobalSolution’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: AFAIK, that should be `_WIN32` and `__linux__`.

Comment: Is `-std=11` actually a valid version flag? Shouldn't it be `-std=c++11`? (may not be relevant)

Comment: I can't speak to windows but on Linux GCC has #define `__linux 1` & `#define __linux__ 1`. Therefore you should do `#ifdef __linux__` to detect for linux.

Comment: @chris Using "_WIN32" and "__linux__" in place of windows and linux worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean, "Re-ask"? How is this not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566842/c11-compilation-refuses-to-accept-if-windows-and-if-linux?

Comment: -1: Do not re-post questions. I want to close your old one as a dupe but my original closevote cannot now be retracted. :(

Comment: For GCC, see [3.7.3 System-specific Predefined Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-specific-Predefined-Macros.html#System-specific-Predefined-Macros) in the GCC manual. The short of it is, you should check for `__unix__` or `__linux__` because they are system-specific macros and part of the reserved namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple constant `linux` is a GCC extension and not an official OS constant. The proper constant for Debian is probably `__gnu_linux__`; you can find a list of them for various systems [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/). Usually official predefined constants follow the convention of using `__` at the start.

Your code works without the standard flag because by default GCC compiles in a GNU language mode (GNU C++) rather than a standard language mode (ISO C++); the GNU language includes extensions (extra language features, and in this case, legacy OS constants). When you pass the `-std=c++11` flag you are requesting ISO language mode, which means GNU extensions are *disabled*, including GNU-only constants. To get both GNU extensions and a specific set of ISO features, try requesting a GNU language standard version instead (e.g. `-std=gnu++11` works fine).